# RP Pico SPI MicoPython write order confusion

Tags: microcontroller, spi, serial

I'm using an RP Pico to program the FT8113 Video Processor, I have written the following code and the device boots up but does not return the expected 0x7C as stated in the datasheet.

The programming guide says:

> 1. Send Host command “CLKEXT” to FT81X, if an external clock is used.
> 2. Send Host command “ACTIVE” to enable the clock to the FT81X. FT81X starts its self-diagnosis process and may take up to 300ms. Alternatively, read REG_ID repeatedly until
>    0x7C is read.

[Full Programming Guide](https://brtchip.com/wp-content/uploads/Support/Documentation/Programming_Guides/ICs/EVE/FT81X_Series_Programmer_Guide.pdf)
See page 11 for above quote

The datasheet states that REG_ID is 0x00302000 and needs to be sent as a 32-bit number, I have tried sending both are BIG and LITTLE endian but I can't seem to work out what I'm doing wrong and why it won't return the expected value, the chip required a dummy byte to be sent which is why I send 0x00 while reading:

```
from machine import SPI, Pin
import time

spi = SPI(1, 40000, sck=Pin(14), mosi=Pin(15), miso=Pin(12)) # Default assignment: sck=Pin(10), mosi=Pin(11), miso=Pin(8)
cs = Pin(4, mode=Pin.OUT, value=1)
pd = Pin(5, mode=Pin.OUT, value=1)

chipid = 0

txdata = b"0x00"
rxdata = 0

pd(0)
time.sleep(1)
pd(1)
time.sleep(1)

try:
    cs(0)  
    spi.write(b"\x00\0x00\0x44")
    
    spi.write(b"\x00\0x46\0x61")
    
    spi.write(b"\x00\0x00\0x00")
finally:
    cs(1)
    
time.sleep(2)

while chipid is not 0x7c:
    cs(0)
    time.sleep(1)
    spi.write(b"\x00\x30\x20\x00")
    rxdata = spi.read(1, 0x00)
    chipid = rxdata
    print(rxdata)
    cs(1)
```

Comment: (1) Your spi = SPI(1, 40000, sck=Pin(14), mosi=Pin(15), miso=Pin(12)), Are you sure the GP pin numbers ***14, 15, 12*** are correct? I think they should be ***10, 11, 12*** (2) Have you done any SPI loopback test to make sure the hardware/software setup is OK?

Comment: if the chip id is a 32 bit number, you'll need to send/receive 4 bytes. Your code is only sending 1.

Comment: @Kartman What makes you think so? `spi.write()` gets an array of 4 bytes to send.